# SQL Server calculate percentage of sql pivot value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I currently have a SQL Server pivot with values per month and per `input sales`

I want to calculate % of `input_sales = 'OK'`.

How can I do this?

```
SIGNED  INPUT_SALES DEALER     D2D  CALLCENTER  INTERNET</tr>
2012-01 NOK          158       1231     309       214
2012-01 OK           417       4634    4047      1491
2011-12 NOK          301       1637     404       245
2011-12 OK           615       4195    4334      1985
```

My Code:

```
SELECT SIGNED_DATE, 
    INPUT_SALES, 
    [DEALER] AS DEALER, 
    [D2D] AS D2D, 
    [CALLCENTER] AS CALLCENTER, 
    [INTERNET] AS INTERNET
FROM
(
    SELECT ENTITLEMENT_ID, SALES_CHANNEL, SIGNED_DATE, INPUT_SALES
    FROM #TEMP
) T
PIVOT
(
    COUNT (ENTITLEMENT_ID)
    FOR SALES_CHANNEL IN
        ([DEALER], [D2D], [CALLCENTER], [INTERNET])
) AS PVT
ORDER BY PVT.SIGNED_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Could you add the column with the desired output on your example data?

Answer (score 0):

should be something like

```
with total as (
select COUNT(INPUT_SALES)as id from t),
counted as (select count(INPUT_SALES) as id from t where t.INPUT_SALES='OK')
select 100.0*counted.INPUT_SALES/total.INPUT_SALES from total,counted
group by total.INPUT_SALES,counted.INPUT_SALES
```

---

hope it helps

Comment: <p>The result I get is just 1 number.../p><p>I've added my code as was in the question now...</p>

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select INPUT_SALES , cast(count(*) as numeric(5,2)) * 100 /(select count(*) from TABLE_INPUT_SALES )
from TABLE_INPUT_SALES 
where INPUT_SALES ='OK'
group by INPUT_SALES
```